# How to write a Spring data jpa method for optional parameter

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
 @Query("select m from MaterialMetadata m where m.myKey= :myKey and m.statusType= :statusType " +
                        "and (m.createdTime>= :startTime or :startTime=0) and (m.createdTime<= :endTime or :endTime=0) " +
                        "and (m.userKey= :userKey or :userKey is null) and (m.title like %:title% or :title is null)")
                Page<MaterialMetadata> findByMyKeyAndStatusTypeAndCreatedTimeAndUserKeyAndTitleContainingIgnoreCase(@Param("myKey") String myKey, @Param("statusType") StatusType statusType, @Param("startTime") long startTime, @Param("endTime") long endTime, @Param("userKey") String userKey, @Param("title") String title, Pageable pageable);
```

write a query where mykey and statusType is a mandatory column and the rest are optional.

In **createdTime** startTime and endTime is could be 0 or they have value, if they have value then search the time in between the start and end time.

if only startTime has value then search from startTime and its above.

if only endTime has value then search from endTime and it's below.

if both do not have any value then search on the rest column.

For **Title**, it could search on a like basis.

Issue -

1. for the title it's returning on an equal basis.
2. For createTime if any of field is missing does not give any output.
3. if any optional field is missing, there is no output

Comment: My opinion is create a query method for each set of criteria and use a method in the service layer to call the appropriate method based on the non null arguments that are passed in.

Comment: I agree with @Calvin here - such approach would also be much easier to read, test & support

Comment: alternatively, you can use JpaSpecifications for dynamic jpa queries. 
https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl

Comment: If you start having more optional criteria, then I agree with @EmanuelTrandafir. JpaSpecifications would be the way to go. For the few optionals you have here, either option would suffice. Again, that’s just my personal opinion.